# Can I use an XSLT stylesheet to display dynamic data?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I posted a question yesterday with some very helpful responses about using jQuery to extract XML data and output to an XML web-page. However as a Javascript/jQuery beginner I am struggling with working with my multiple page and complex XML sheet.

I am trying to display the in-game statistics generated by my university's basketball statistics crew. Here is an example of the XML code....

```
<player uni="01" code="01" name="PLAYER" checkname="PLAYER, 1" gp="1">
      <stats fgm="1" fga="3" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="2" fta="3" tp="4" blk="1" stl="1" ast="0" min="15" oreb="0" dreb="2" treb="2" pf="2" tf="0" to="2" dq="0"></stats>
```

Is there a way to use an XSLT stylesheet to output this XML data in an HTML web-page where the data will change in real-time? I initially tried setting the webpage to refresh every few seconds but it creates this annoying flickering effect.

Is there a Javascript function I can incorporate or a XSLT tool I can use to do this?

Basically I would like when a players fgm (field-goals-made) changes, i.e he makes a basket, for the XSLT formed HTML website to display the resulting changes fairly quickly. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I have looked around on this website and haven't really found any good examples of how to do this.

Comment: Take a look at [Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) - it is an XSLT 2.0 processor implemented in JavaScript, which among other things allows you to define XSLT templates that fire on JavaScript events, and to call transformations from JavaScript that fill in just particular parts of the DOM rather than re-rendering the whole page.

Comment: @IanRoberts Taking a look at that right now. Thanks.